# ESP32 Task watchdog got triggered using ESP IDF

Tags: esp32, watchdog, esp-idf

We need to read ADC module over I2C continuously 20 times to get stable values of ADC.
We have created a task for it, but code stop working in couple of min showing below error.

```
E (1925655) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not r
eset the watchdog in time:
E (1925655) task_wdt:  - IDLE (CPU 0)
E (1925655) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (1925655) task_wdt: CPU 0: esp_timer
```

We are not getting any exact solution for our error. Below is the task espfor reference.

```c
void Hal_Read_Average_Voltage_For_TLA202x (void *pvParameters)
{
    float read_value = 0, bigger_value = 0, voltage = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        Hal_TLA2024_Re_Initialize ();

        {
            for (int count1 = 0; count1 < 20; count1++)
            {
                voltage = readVoltage ();    //Performs I2C register read
                if (voltage > bigger_value)
                {
                    bigger_value = voltage;
                }
                vTaskDelay (1);
            }

            read_value += bigger_value;

            bigger_value = 0;
        }

        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "ADC Highest Value = %f\n", (read_value));
        read_value = 0;
        bigger_value = 0;
        voltage = 0;

        vTaskDelay (300 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}




float readVoltage (void)
{
  int16_t raw_voltage;
  uint16_t u16TempRead = 0;
    uint8_t u8TempRead[2] = { 0, 0 };
    uint8_t u8TempAddress = TLA202x_DATA_REG;

    Hal_I2C_Read_Register (TLA202x_I2CADDR_DEFAULT, u8TempAddress, u8TempRead, 2, 1);

    u16TempRead = u8TempRead[1] | (u8TempRead[0] << 8);

    raw_voltage =  u16TempRead;
  // this will read the sign bit correctly, but shifting will move the bit out
  // of the msbit
  if (raw_voltage & 0x8000)
    {
      raw_voltage >>= 4;
      raw_voltage |= 0x8000;
    }
  else
    {
      raw_voltage >>= 4;
    }
  switch (current_range)
    {
    case TLA202x_RANGE_6_144_V:
      voltage = raw_voltage *= 3;
      break;
    case TLA202x_RANGE_4_096_V:
      voltage = raw_voltage *= 2;
      break;
    case TLA202x_RANGE_2_048_V:
      voltage = raw_voltage *= 1;
      break;
    case TLA202x_RANGE_1_024_V:
      voltage = raw_voltage *= 0.5;
      break;
    case TLA202x_RANGE_0_512_V:
      voltage = raw_voltage *= 0.25;
      break;
    case TLA202x_RANGE_0_256_V:
      voltage = raw_voltage *= 0.125;
      break;
    }
  voltage /= 1000.0; // mV =>V

  return voltage;
}




void Hal_I2C_Read_Register (uint32_t slave_address, int register_address, uint8_t read_data_buffer[],
                uint8_t read_buffer_length, uint8_t write_buffer_length)
{
  i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd;

DATA_READ: cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create ();
  i2c_master_start (cmd);
  if (register_address != -1)
    {
      i2c_master_write_byte (cmd, slave_address << 1 | I2C_MASTER_WRITE,
      ACK_CHECK_EN);
      i2c_master_write_byte (cmd, register_address, ACK_CHECK_EN);
      i2c_master_start (cmd);
    }
  i2c_master_write_byte (cmd, slave_address << 1 | I2C_MASTER_READ,
  ACK_CHECK_EN);
  if (read_buffer_length > 1)
    {
      i2c_master_read (cmd, read_data_buffer, read_buffer_length - 1, ACK_VAL);
    }
  i2c_master_read_byte (cmd, read_data_buffer + read_buffer_length - 1,
  NACK_VAL);
  i2c_master_stop (cmd);
  esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin (I2C_NUM_0, cmd, 1000/ portTICK_RATE_MS);
  i2c_cmd_link_delete (cmd);
  if (ret == ESP_OK)
    {

    }
  else if (ret == ESP_ERR_TIMEOUT)
    {
//    ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Bus is busy");
    }
  else
    {
      ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Read failed %d", ret);
      goto DATA_READ;
    }
}
```

We are having 2 more thread running on same priority.
If we remove the for loop in the above thread then there is no WDT error.

Comment: Do you get WDT timeout if you keep the loop, but do not call `readVoltage()`?

Comment: No WDT error when we remove  readVoltage().

Comment: Thats mat be a clue for you. If you cannot figure it out, you should add the code for that function.

Comment: Added the code for `readVoltage()`.
Even if we run this single thread it gives us same wdt error after some time.
Our use case is to read data from I2C continuously 20 times it loop, just need a workaround for that.

Comment: There is `esp_timer` task running on core 0 when the WDT triggers. You're not running this loop of yours off a timer callback, are you? Interrupts and timer callbacks are not meant for doing anything long-lasting. Your normal application thread(s) need to do that. Timers just fire events that the main thread listens for, and processes.

Comment: Do you have a link to a definition/description for `Hal_I2C_Read_Register`? I can't seem to find it. I'm looking to see how it's described. The only functions I've found close to that are all defined in STM32 libraries, not ESP32. Or is it one of your functions?

Comment: Added `Hal_I2C_Read_Register()`. Those are all user defined functions written by me.

Answer (score 0):

Updated ESP-IDF version to 4.4 and it solved this issue.